# Angular Material old theming to version 16 - css variable

Tags: sass, angular-material

I am converting to Angular Material 16.
I was able to convert the palettes but not sure about the CSS variables.

In my old .scss file I had:

```
                    // set variables of colors based on our $default-theme
$primary: map-get($default-theme, primary);
$accent: map-get($default-theme, accent);
$warn: map-get($default-theme, warn);
...

                // create CSS 4 style variables
:root {
  --color-primary:            #{mat-color($primary)};
  --color-accent:             #{mat-color($accent)};
  --color-warn:               #{mat-color($warn)};
```

Can you please help to convert this for usage in the new version with the

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
....
```